# Why is the root user named root by default?

Tags: linux, user-management, root

This might seem like a silly question but I could see this as being confusing. For example:

"Go to root directory"

Could be interpreted as:

1. Go to `/`
2. Go to `~root` (usually `/root/`)

I would think something like `super` would of made for a better default administrator username. This would avoid the ambiguity with directory structure.

Again: Silly question but I'm genuinely curious.

Comment: the "root directory" is always `/`, root's home is `~root`. A side note, on BSD systems root has the name "Charlie Root".

Comment: I am aware that root directory = `/`. Maybe that was a bad example. I just see where there could be confusion.

Comment: In older versions of UNIX (and Linux distributions) root's home directory was / instead of /root.

Comment: As an addition to what Gerald pointed out, Solaris 10 has (had?) this same behavior.

Comment: What's in a name? That which we call a rose, By any other name would smell as sweet.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Have a look [**here**](http://www.linfo.org/root.html) for some information on root.

> The use of the term root for the
>   all-powerful administrative user may
>   have arisen from the fact that root is
>   the only account having write
>   permissions (i.e., permission to
>   modify files) in the root directory.
>   The root directory, in turn, takes its
>   name from the fact that the
>   filesystems (i.e., the entire
>   hierarchy of directories that is used
>   to organize files) in Unix-like
>   operating systems have been designed
>   with a tree-like (although inverted)
>   structure in which all directories
>   branch off from a single directory
>   that is analogous to the root of a
>   tree.

Comment: Interesting.  Glad that the question was asked!

Comment: Great answer @lain, +1. Although "maybe have arisen" doesn't affirmative, makes lots of sense. And @Mark: Wish I could +1 an edit but think you have enough rep as it is ;-)